# Can I execute queries on Data Explorer from my program

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, database

Is there a way to query the Database directly, from my app?

Comment: Head over to http://stackoverflow.com, man.

Comment: Before asking how I could do it, I want to know if I could do it.

Comment: FWIW, this seems on topic to me.

Comment: *Which* database? Stack Overflow's one?

Comment: Any of the one features in the Site.

Comment: im not following, are you asking for some API for data explorer, can you expand your question please?

Comment: Yeah, some king of api that let me pass a query and get the result or execute a query that is already in the site.

Answer (score 1):

- You can download [the data dumps](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/)
  (which the data explorer is a
  front-end to) and access those from
  your app.
- The data explorer supports the [OData](http://www.odata.org/) protocol.
- For simple queries you can use [the API](https://stackapps.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no official API for Data Explorer, but most of the wiring is in place, the source is open http://odata.stackexchange.com/faq, a patch with documentation and a cleaner end point would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

Head over to [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) for how to use the API