# Are there any ways to petition to increase your Stack Exchange API limit?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, meta, api

I know there is a 10,000 query limit for the Stack Exchange API, but I was curious if there was any way to ask for a one-time increase of API requests as I just need to do a one-time pull to get a bit of data.

Comment: If its a one time pull, why not grab the datadump?

Comment: @Aibobot I have a list of owner_user_id for various questions and answer information I pulled from the API for 88 different tags ('SO', 'Math', etc), and I need the reputation histories for each of the users -- is this something I could use the data dump for?

Comment: @HermSang with the data dump, you can do anything, you just have to write the query yourself, e.g. if you import it to a database, you can use SQL. SEDE might be more simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know of one instance where that happened: [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/) got a [doubled API quota](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36038378) but that was after years of proven service to the community (and only after we've asked for it a couple of times), so it was clearly an exception.

I discovered by accident that the Stack Exchange mobile apps have [unlimited quota](https://stackapps.com/q/8168/34061) but it's probably against the Terms of Service to issue more than 10,000 requests per day with it.

A better option would be to spread out the calls over several days. I'm not sure how many calls you want to make? Do note that the [reputation history](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-history) call supports multiple user IDs, and you can increase the page size to 100.

This table isn't present in SEDE, but I think you can come pretty close with data that *is* available, e.g. [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1170724/reputation-graph#graph) accurately predicts my current Meta reputation to 0.3%. (Note that SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday morning.) I haven't checked the API, but I'm not sure it would do better, since (like SEDE) it doesn't include private reputation events. SEDE doesn't have an API but I've posted a workaround [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341993/295232); you can also use the data dump to fire up your own local SEDE instance. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28221/295232) are some scripts for this.