# Is it abusive to use a sockpuppet account for API calls?

Tags: support, user-accounts, api, sock-puppets, multiple-accounts

Other questions ask about acceptable use of sockpuppet accounts, but I'm interested in if using multiple sockpuppet accounts for API calls. In my mind the answer would be that they're not abusive because these API calls could be performed by any one user, but it might not be okay because multiple accounts could be used to make multiple times the API limit. I was wondering this because I don't want to use the API limit of my main account, so I thought about creating a sockpuppet account to use in development, and another for production.

Comment: I assume you also split that over multiple IP-addresses then? So one IP for dev and another one for production?

Comment: @rene Yes, but I ended up using the IP limit really fast.

Comment: The IP limit is the main problem. Most chat bots run on sock accounts and one major api consumer, Smoke Detector, also runs under a sock-account. That by itself is not abusive. it becomes abusive once the SRE notices your activity due to the higher-load and/or spikes in the performance and throughput stats.

Comment: If you don't use multiple accounts to "scale up" I assume there is no problem.

Comment: @rene But would it be considered scaling up to have two accounts, one for development and one for production?

Comment: well, I assume you don't reach the limits on your dev account that you would on production.

Comment: An *unofficial* answer: [10K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353096/282094) requests, subject to the [rate limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/282094). Doing anything to sidestep the limits is obviously unwanted.

Comment: Are you trying to get around limitations imposed by the system without permission? If "yes", then "Yes, it's abusive of the system." If "no", then "no, it's not abusive of the system."

Comment: It's unclear to me what part of what you're asking isn't answered by the proposed duplicate, which says "**if the second account allows you to do something on the site that your normal account would be prevented from doing, it is abuse.**" However, the wording of your question implies you've read other questions about sockpuppets, presumably including the one which I've proposed as a duplicate, and that they didn't answer the question which you actually have. If you feel it's not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to make it clear what about your question isn't answered by the duplicate.