# How to run a Stack Exchange data query with the Stack Exchange API

Tags: support, data-explorer, user-accounts, api

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to run a query/complex search on the Stack Exchange API.

I need to find all users that have a reputation greater than 250 and are from a certain location. I made the query and it works fine in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. Now I'm wondering if there is a way to get the response using a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) request (or to run the same query with a REST client).

Comment: The (reasonable) expectation is a REST interface, but it uses old school [query parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Answer (score 3):

[SEDE doesn't have an API yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264678/295232), and the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users) does not offer a filter on location. I guess you *could* fetch **all** users (ordered by reputation, descending) and let your client do the filtering; you can retrieve [100 users per page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging), so (assuming you have a [registered application with increased quota](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle)), you can do that for 100 × 10,000 = 1 million users per day. That [should be enough](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1651380) ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know if there are any tutorials/guides where I can check how to set up the AUTH then to get the users , all I'm looking for a way to log in and get all the users, already took care of the rest
P.s. this its the hardest task I got for a junior position

Comment: @AndrewGremus if it's a one of, you can also download the SEDE results as CSV and process that...